# fetch customerId for myApiClient

Tags: node.js, swift, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am trying to fetch the customerId for myAPIClient using swift firebase and node.js. When I run my application it crashes and tells me that the customerId is nil. The reason that I am needing this customerId is in order to create the ephemeralKey.

The code that I use in node.js is,

```
exports.createEphemeralKey = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
const stripe_version = req.body.api_version;
const customerId = req.body.customerId

if (!stripe_version) {
console.log('I did not see any api version')
res.status(400).end()
return;
}

stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
{customer: customerId},
{stripe_version: apiVersion}
).then((key) => {
 console.log("Ephemeral key: " + key)
 res.status(200).json(key)
}).catch((err) => {
console.log('stripe version is ' + stripe_version + " and customer id is " + customerId + " for key: " + stripe_key + " and err is " + err.message )
res.status(500).json(err)
});
});
```

and the code that I am using inside of myApiClient is.

```
    func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
  let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("ephemeral_keys")
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let customerId = defaults.string(forKey: "customerId")
    AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: [
        "api_version": apiVersion, "customer_id": customerId!
        ])
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseJSON { responseJSON in
            switch responseJSON.result {
            case .success(let json):
                completion(json as? [String: AnyObject], nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(nil, error)
            }
    }
}
```

I have been stuck on creating this ephemeralKey for a while now and have asked other questions but have not gotten a real answer. Is there anything that I am missing? How can I actually access the customersId from stripe inside of my ios project.

Comment: What is your `responseJSON` like in the iOS code? The ephemeralKey returned from Stripe might not contain customer_id you'd expect. And to create a EphemeralKey you will need to `first` get a customer id and send over to the backend as a request parameter. How are you planning to get the customer ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first check that `let customerId = defaults.string(forKey: "customerId")` provides a valid customerId. You can do so by debugging your app and inspecting the value of `customerId`. Assuming that it is valid, I see a couple of things that may be causing issues for you:

The Alamofire library that you are using has 2 Parameter Encoders with different properties and options. You can see them [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#request-parameters-and-parameter-encoders).
My hypothesis is that you are nor passing the `customerId` correclty to the body of the request. I suggest you start by trying the [JSONParameterEncoder](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#jsonparameterencoder). Your request would be somehting like this:

```
AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: [
  "api_version": apiVersion, "customer_id": customerId!
  ],
  encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default)
```

It is possible that you also have to tweak the way your retrieve the customerID from the Cloud Function according to how you pass the info from the swift app. This [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#parsing_http_requests) may provide some insights on how to parse HTTP request info